# Ruby on Rails: How can I add a css file with rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

The application.html.erb file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Site</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    :all %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

I have a file "cake.generic.css" in public/ folder.

But when I reload the page the effect of css file is not working.

If I see the page view source I see something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Site</title>
  <link href="/assets/all.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/home.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="6CPvchXr1amagxd7VmOzB82WGx/WmjfDOXjMLfjLzqQ=" name="csrf-token" />
</head>
<body>

<h1>Home#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/home/index.html.erb</p>


</body>
</html>
```

What should I do to fix this problem?

How can I set the public folder for stylesheets and javascripts?

It looks that app/assets folder is set for css and js files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rails is likely consolidating all your css files into one that it is calling assets/all.css

Consider using the free plug-ins [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) + [firepath](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firepath/?src=search) to further characterize the problem.  This common combo of tools will help you to interrogate web page elements and see the css that is contributing to their display.

Comment: I had to put the css file in app/assets folder.

Answer (score 5):

Copy `cake.generic.css` to the folder `public/assets/`, if not exists make directory first.

then add this to you `erb` 

`<%= stylesheet_link_tag "cake.generic" %>`

*2nd question: How can i set the public folder for stylesheets and javascripts ?*

Just put all you images, js and css file under 'public/assets/' and then include them in the `erb` pages

*3rd question: It looks that app/assets folder is set for css and js files ?*

Yes, 'app/assets/stylesheets/' for css and scss file
and 'app/assets/javascripts'  for js and coffeescript file

You can get more info here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#how-to-use-the-asset-pipeline

Hope this work for you:)

Answer (score 3):

Your Style sheet should be placed in the following directory `\public\stylesheets` from your root project and also if you want to specify different location provide an absolute path inside `stylesheet_link_tag("/public/yourfolder/test.css")`

Comment: Still error, i used this => <%= stylesheet_link_tag("/public/cake.generic.css") %>

Comment: Also tried this creating a folder "stylesheets", still error, <%= stylesheet_link_tag("/public/stylesheets//cake.generic.css") %>

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue, but my fix was to make sure the css is under app/assets/stylesheets/   and I had to add the below line to the application.css file (my css file is named custom.css)

@import 'custom'

Comment: this might solve the problem but doesn't answer the question 'How can I set the public folder for stylesheets and javascripts?'