# Stylesheets in Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, stylesheet

I would like to use one of my stylesheets from the public folder (several directories each with their own css file) for one of my controllers.

Having trouble bringing in the static css file.

I've tried the following code -

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "/public/foldername/style2.css" %>
```

But it's not working

Comment: Similar post like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689609/ruby-on-rails-how-can-i-add-css-file-with-rails-project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "/foldername/style2.css" %>
```