# Loading asset to view in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to load a css file from the asset folder, but it does not seem to work. May I ask what is the right way to do, say the file is as:

```
AppName > App > assets > css_home > animate.css
```

I tried:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css_home/animate.css">
```

But it does not seem to work.

Comment: You can't do this in this way, Rails(with the asset pipeline)  is just bundling all css files into one. Basically you need to import your css in `applications.css`. Follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689609/ruby-on-rails-how-can-i-add-a-css-file-with-rails-project or https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives The wacky-way would be to put animate.css to the public folder.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ruby on Rails: How can I add a css file with rails project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689609/ruby-on-rails-how-can-i-add-a-css-file-with-rails-project)

Comment: Ok, I did it for the CSS and it works, how should I do for the javascript please : <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-3.5.1-min" %> does not seem to work

Comment: jquery really depends on your ruby and rails versions. I have an `import "jquery"` in my `application.js` file, and some tweaks in my `environment.js` file to get it working.

Comment: The same way that all css files are bundled into one, js files are too. If you just need jquery, use gem this https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails then add `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>` to your layout header. I highly suggest that you just read this https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#how-to-use-the-asset-pipeline it contains all information regarding asset pipeline in Rails.

Comment: sorry, i have a few of them actually,   i am trying to bring : <%= javascript_include_tag "modernizr-3.7.1.min" %>,   <%= javascript_include_tag "wow.min" %>
and more. Apologies, I should have mentionned that earlier.
,